# How to use a variable from an Angular Service

Tags: angular

Inside of my Angular Service I have a method that I do the logic for getting the next item, in a pagination. This method returns the name of the page where I will navigate if I click next on pagination buttons.

Because I did the logic in this method, from here I need the active class, to implement it in the sidebar component. In the sidebar I have to set the active url to mach my link and to make it diff color with css.

The navigate method from my Service

```
private _pages = [
{name: '/page1', index: 0}, 
{name: '/page2', index: 1}, 
{name: '/page3', index: 2}
];    

public activeClass;
private _current = null;

public getCurrent() {
    return this._current;
}

public navigate(action: string) {
    if (typeof this.ACTIONS[action] === 'undefined')
      return;

    let shift = this.ACTIONS[action];
    this.setCurrent(shift);

    const curr = this.getCurrent();
    this.activeClass = 'done-' + curr.index;
    return this.router.navigate([curr.name]);
}
```

In my sidebar I injected the service and in the ts file I want to get the activeClass from my Service like this:

```
public activeClasss() { 
    this.activeClass = this.PrevNextService.activeClass;
  }
```

And to use it in the sidebar html like this:

```
<div class="list-group-wrapper" [ngClass]="activeClasss()">
```

Of course I did some SASS rules that with a for loop takes care of each class.

My problem is that I can't take that activeClass from my Service in the way that I put above, because I get an error. I can't declare this activeClass outside my navigate(), from Service, because in navigate() I create the logic that when I use it I can see the current url.

So is it any way to get this

```
this.activeClass = 'done-' + curr.index;
```

from my Service method and use it the sidebar ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with your code? In HTML you use a function:

```
<div class="list-group-wrapper" [ngClass]="activeClasss()">
```

But that function does not return anything

```
public activeClasss() { 
    this.activeClass = this.PrevNextService.activeClass;
}
```

Use in template Component variable or return something from function. Code you have should be working fine...